# Substitute spaces with new line in selection in Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to substitute all spaces with a new line inside curly brackets. This is what I did:

- selected the content inside(`vi{`)
- ran substitute command: `s/\%V /\r/g`

but Vim is substituting only the first occurrence of space. I am not sure what am I missing here. Here is the line on which I'm doing this operation:

```js
import { setNotificationContent, toggleContext, resetContext } from '../../redux/modules/wrapper/wrapper'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening.  You first select the visual area with `vi{`.  This sets the positions of the two marks `<` and `>`.  The `s` command only matches within these marks due to `\%V`.  But what do these marks mean after the first   is replaced with a newline?  The old notion of "visual area" is certainly gone, but the question is if the substitute command can keep up with the new notion of the text being replaced.  I guess vim roughly "does the substitution and increments the current line number by the number of newlines inserted."  Normally this works just fine, but you have the `\%V` operator in your match, so nothing will match after the current line number is incremented.  (See the [source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/ex_cmds.c) for more details, hit `ctrl-f multi-line` to find relevant parts).

To just get the substitutions you probably want in this case, you can use:

```
s/\({\|,\) \| }\@=/\1\r/g
```

To get a feel of how the visual selection really just sets those marks, select some visual area, and press `gv`.  It will reselect that visual area.  Hit `:marks` to see the locations of `<` and `>`.  Now edit that area you previously selected, and check to see if the locations of the marks changed (same goes for other marks).  Note that vim is somewhat smart, and will keep track of the right line numbers when some lines are inserted or deleted above, but it doesn't update column numbers.

To see how the current line increments on multiple substitutions, try this out.  Say we have the line:

```
aaa
```

Now, we run the `s` command:

```
:s/a/\= line('.') . '_'/g
```

`\=` replaces the string with the result of the expression, see `:help sub-replace`.  The result should look something like

```
6_6_6_
```

I'm on line 6, that's why my result is so metal.  Now, `u`ndo that, and run this `s` command:

```
:s/a/\= line('.') . "\n"/g
```

Now, instead of an `_`, we're appending a newline after the line number.  I get the result:

```
6
7
8
```

So that `line('.')` function is being called each time, and on a different current line.  Tada!

Oh yea, one interesting corallary to the way vim keeps track of marks is that if you have the following lines:

```
import { something, something, something
}
```

Then do `ga{` (!not `giv`), the run the `s` command

```
s/\%V /r/g
```

You get roughly the behavior you want (depending on whether or not you removed the trailing whitespace).  The proof is left as an exercise, and research assignment as to why you need `ga{` and not `gi{` (hint: check out `:help {` and `:help exclusive`).